# Subtract dates in Ruby and get the difference in minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

how do i subtract two different UTC dates in Ruby and then get the difference in minutes?

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

(time1 - time2) / 60

If the time objects are string, `Time.parse(time)` them first

Comment: Depends if the objects in question are Time objects or Date objects. Time#- returns the number of seconds, while Date#- returns the number of days.

Comment: Almost the same but `(time1 - time2) / 1.minute` might be more readable.

Answer (score 63):

If you subtract two Date or DateTime objects, the result is a Rational representing the number of days between them. What you need is:

```
a = Date.new(2009, 10, 13) - Date.new(2009, 10, 11)
(a * 24 * 60).to_i   # 2880 minutes
```

or

```
a = DateTime.new(2009, 10, 13, 12, 0, 0) - DateTime.new(2009, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0)
(a * 24 * 60).to_i   # 3600 minutes
```

Comment: Not sure if it may have changed between versions (Chubas's answer is common around the Internet), but as of version 1.9.3p364 this is the correct answer.

Comment: I think my answer has been correct since before 1.9.3 was released :)

Comment: The second part of the answer is not correct. `DateTime` returns number of seconds, and the accepted answer should be applied in that case - meaning `(DateTime.new - DateTime.new)/60`

Comment: My answer is correct as of Ruby 2.1. I haven't tried newer versions.

Answer (score 23):

https://rubygems.org/gems/time_difference - Time Difference gem for Ruby

```
start_time = Time.new(2013,1)
end_time = Time.new(2014,1)
TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_minutes
```

Comment: TimeDifference gem is a great solution

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two dates `task_signed_in` and `task_signed_out` for a simple `@user` object. We could do like this:

```
(@user.task_signed_out.to_datetime - @user.task_signed_in.to_datetime).to_i
```

This will give you result in days. Multiply by `24` you will get result in hours and again multiply by `60` you will result in minutes and so on.

This is the most up to date solution tested in ruby 2.3.x and above.