# Return minutes in DateTime subtraction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

The following returns `(5/12)`, a `Rational` object.

```
d = DateTime.current
d2 = d + 10.hours
d2 - d
```

How would I get the minute difference from the two points in time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subtract dates in Ruby and get the difference in minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852605/subtract-dates-in-ruby-and-get-the-difference-in-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(d2 - d).class
=> Rational
```

> [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Rational.html): A rational number can be represented as a paired integer number; a/b (b>0). Where a is numerator and b is denominator. Integer a equals rational a/1 mathematically.

```
d2 - d
=> (5/12)  #get the number of days

((d2 - d) * 24 * 60).to_i
=> 600    # get the number of minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTimes are all ultimately just a single number, float or int, under the  hood, with the number representing seconds since epoch.  When you do addition and subtraction it's doing the maths with these numbers,  If it makes sense for the result to be a datetime it will usually return a datetime, but if it doesn't, it will just give you the number back.

When you subtract a time from another, the difference is a number of seconds.  The `Rational` class is a way of holding the number, as an fraction rather than as a Float or Int.

Calling `to_i` or `to_f` will convert the number into an int or a float, depending on your requirements.  You've then got a number of seconds, and you can convert this into a number of minutes by dividing it by 60.

Watch out for this gotcha:  in ruby, if you divide an int by an int, it will round down the result to keep it an int.  eg

```
90/60
=> 1
```

If you want a float back, 1.5 in this case, make sure at least one of the operands of the division is a float.

so, this should work:

```
d = DateTime.current
d2 = d + 10.hours
diff_minutes = (d2 - d)/60.0
```

Comment: why are you divide 60.0 by (d2-d)?

Comment: To make this absolutely obvious, replace `60.0` with `1.minute`. You compute the timespan, then divide it by one minute... effectively getting the number of minutes that fit in it.

Comment: @D-side but The OP want to get the minute difference

Comment: @pangpang yes, that's what it does. What about it?

Comment: Duh. Checked this. It fails indeed.

Comment: ah, i beg your pardon, that must be a different behaviour in your version of ruby: mine uses seconds for DateTime too.

Comment: I'm having days in DateTime and seconds in Time. Ruby 2.2.3p173.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_diff = date_2 - date_1
date_diff_array = Date.day_fraction_to_time(diff) # => [h, m, s, frac_s]

date_diff_array[0] # hours 
date_diff_array[1] # minutes 
date_diff_array[2] # seconds
```