# Given a timestamp, how to determine how many weeks ago?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to return the number of weeks since a user was created in my app..

My model is User.rb (id, created_at)

Given `user.created_at`:

```
2.4.0 :008 > user.created_at
 => Mon, 14 Aug 2017 15:51:23 UTC +00:00
```

How can I do something like: `user.created_at.weeks_ago` where it returns some integer which represents the number of weeks since the user was created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to build a human-friendly string, I believe `time_ago_in_words` is what you are after.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words

Otherwise, I would resort to something like the following:

```
(Time.new - user.created_at) / 1.week
```

If you want a more elegant solution, [Subtract dates in Ruby and get the difference in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852605/subtract-dates-in-ruby-and-get-the-difference-in-minutes) mentions [the Time Difference gem for Ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_difference).

e.g.

```
TimeDifference.between(user.created_at.to_time, Time.now).in_weeks
```

Comment: Rails has a method `1.week` you can use instead of the 'magic' numbers: `1.week == (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)`

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
Time.current
 => Wed, 20 Sep 2017 03:56:15 UTC +00:00
```

Then

```
((Time.current - person.created_at)/604800).to_i
```

the subtraction gives you the number of seconds then divide it by `604800` which is the number of seconds in a week.

Comment: Rails has a method 1.week you can use instead of the 'magic' number: `1.week == 604800`